# Identify Min & Max Numeric Value within Date/Datetime range repeatedly

Tags: r, datetime, data-analysis, finance, date-range

I am completely new to R so this is proving too complex to handle for me right now, so any help is much appreciated.

I am analysing price action data for BTC. I have 1 minute candles from 2019-09-08 19:13:00 to 2022-03-15 00:22:00 with the variables of open, high, low, close price as well as volume in BTC & USD and trade count for each of those minutes. Data source is https://www.cryptodatadownload.com/data/binance/ for anyone interested.

I cleaned up & correctly formatted the data and now want to analyse when BTC price made a low & high for various date & time ranges, for example:

What time of day in 30 minute increments did BTC made a low for the week?

Here is what I believe I need to do:
I need to tell R that 30 minutes is a range and identify the lowest & highest value for the "Low" and "High" variables within in as well as that a day is a range and within that the lowest & highest value for the "Low" and "High" variables as well as define a week as a range and within that the lowest & highest value for the "Low" and "High" variables.
Then I'd need to mark these values, the best method I can think of would be creating a new variable and have it as a TRUE/FALSE column like so:

```
btcusdt_binance_fut_1min$pa.low.of.week.30min
btcusdt_binance_fut_1min$pa.high.of.week.30min
```

Every minute row that is within that 30min low and high will be marked TRUE and every other minute within that week will be marked FALSE.

I looked at lubridate's interval() function but as far as I know the problem is I'd need to define each year, month, week, day, 30mins interval individually with start and end time, which is obviously not feasible. I believe I run into the same problem with the subset() function.

Another option seems to be the seq() and seq.POSIXt() functions as well as the range() function, but I haven't found a way for it.

Here is all my code and I am using this data set: https://www.cryptodatadownload.com/cdd/BTCUSDT_Binance_futures_data_minute.csv

```
library(readr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)


# IMPORT CSV FILE AS DATA SET

# Name data set & choose import file
# Skip = 1 for skipping first row of CSV
btcusdt_binance_fut_1min <-
  read.csv(
    file.choose(),
    skip = 1,
    header = T,
    sep = ","
  )


# CLEAN UP & REORGANISE DATA

# Remove unix & symbol column
btcusdt_binance_fut_1min$unix = NULL
btcusdt_binance_fut_1min$symbol = NULL

# Rename date column to datetime
colnames(btcusdt_binance_fut_1min)[colnames(btcusdt_binance_fut_1min) == "date"] <-
  "datetime"

# Convert datetime column to POSIXct format
btcusdt_binance_fut_1min$datetime <-
  as_datetime(btcusdt_binance_fut_1min$datetime, tz = "UTC")

# Create variable column for each time element
btcusdt_binance_fut_1min$year <-
  year(btcusdt_binance_fut_1min$datetime)
btcusdt_binance_fut_1min$month <-
  month(btcusdt_binance_fut_1min$datetime)
btcusdt_binance_fut_1min$week <-
  isoweek(btcusdt_binance_fut_1min$datetime)
btcusdt_binance_fut_1min$weekday <-
  wday(btcusdt_binance_fut_1min$datetime,
       label = TRUE,
       abbr = FALSE)
btcusdt_binance_fut_1min$hour <-
  hour(btcusdt_binance_fut_1min$datetime)
btcusdt_binance_fut_1min$minute <-
  minute(btcusdt_binance_fut_1min$datetime)

# Reorder columns
btcusdt_binance_fut_1min <-
  btcusdt_binance_fut_1min[, c(1, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8)]
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. When you talk about a "low", do you mean the lowest 30 minute average value or do you mean the 30 minutes in which the lowest 1 minute value took place? Could you please provide some sample data with an expected output?

Comment: Yes, "Low" as in financial candlestick data terms. So the "Low" of a price is the lowest price went within the 30 minute interval from 11:30 - 12:00 for example.

"Open" -> price at the start of the 30 minutes interval
"High" -> highest price went during the 30 minute interval
"Low" -> lowest price went during the 30 minute interval
"Close" -> price at the end of the 30 minutes increment

But I have 1 minute data, and each 1 minute has it's own open, high, low & close (OHLC) data. So to find the 30 minute "Low", R has to group those 30 rows together and identify the lowest value...

Comment: ... of the variable "Low" within those 30 rows and mark it as the 30min low. OHLC are all separate columns/variables within my data set, so identifying it is not hard, I am more struggling with the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` we can do the following:

```
btcusdt_binance_fut_1min <- data.table(datetime = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 0:00"), as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 2:59"), by = "1 min"))
btcusdt_binance_fut_1min[, group := format(as.POSIXct(cut(datetime, breaks = "30 min")), "%H:%M")]
```

the `cut` function will "floor" each datetime to it's nearest, smaller, half an hour. The `format` and `as.POSIXct` are just there to remove the date part to allow for easy comparing between dates for the same half hours, but if you prefer to keep it a datetime you can remove these functions.

After this the next steps are pretty straightforward:

```
btcusdt_binance_fut_1min[, .(High = max(High), Low = min(Low)), by=.(group)]
```